# Comparing 2 or more groups over 3 sessions

Tags: r, regression, time-series, hypothesis-testing

So far I've done only simple and multi-variant linear regression analysis using R. 
Now I need to do something new and I'm somewhat clueless.

I have four groups of students, with 7 people in each group.
The people of each group, come on day 1, learn a series of words and are tested on those - the learning of and testing on the list is repeated 2 more times on that day. 
On the next day, Day 2, the process repeats for the same list (3 times).
The process repeats one last time after 6 days.

Of course there are differences between the learning styles of the groups, and that is what I would like to test - hence assigning dummy variables to the groups. But I don't know how to start when dealing with time series (that also appear to be "seasonal")

> ```
>       D11 D12 D13         D21 D22 D23     D31 D32 D33
>
> layal     0   1   0       0   7   9       8   12  11
> amir      0   2   2       1   9   15      11  18  22
> rozan     0   4   8       4   12  13      11  16  22
> adam      0   0   0       2   8   11      12  22  22
> bushra    1   9   13      8   20  24              
>  nelly    1   1   4       6   8   17      19  24  24
> bshara    0   1   4       4   6   10      18  20  22
>
>
> andalus   0   0   0       0   4   5       0   5   6
> omar      0   1   1       0   5   5       3   3   7
> almat     0   1   0       0   0   2       2   2   4
> wateen    0   0   0       1   2   9       8   11  11
> mohamed   0   0   2       0   7   9       6   12  14
> nihal     2   3   5       4   9   13      16  18  18
> antwan    1   0   2       6   6   9       16  16  18
>
>
> maysam    0   1   0       4   4   4       4   8   9
> nortan    0   0   1       2   4   3       2   6   6
> samer     0   4   4       4   8   11      10  14  18
> karolin   2   3   4       4   4   5       4   7   10
> mostafa   0   2   2       0   6   7       5   12  12
> talia     0   0   0       0   0   4       6   8   12
> diana     1   2   6       10  11  17      16  23  24
>
> gabriela  0   9  13      20   22  24      24  24  24
> mariam    1   2   1       5   4   3       5   4   3
> ninette   0   0   2       3   3   5       5   9   9
> suzan     0   1   1       2   4   7       5   8   11
> siwar     0   0   0       3   1   2       2   8   8
> angel     0   2   1       7   10  12      14  16  18
> nahla     1   2   0       2   1   3       5   9   12
> ```

Thank you in advance!
Herman

Comment: Did you  give a gap in training  on DAY 4 & day.5 AS WELL ?

Comment: Please edit your question- change tags . Delete regression and r.  I HAve been debarred w.r.t.  my edit priviledge -  I would have done it myself !

Comment: why? R is because I'm asking how to do it in r. And regression is there because right now I can solve for just one average for each member (using dummy var for each group)

Comment: There are no days 4 and 5.
The days are Sunday, Monday and Sunday a week later. 
In each one of those, they learned and tested 3 times.

Comment: Please correct first sentence of 2nd para for  -  four etc. And state details about learning styles.

Comment: Thanks I fixed it. 
But the learning styles aren't relevant here actually. 
I could say one was just listening, another one reading another writing and another a combo. Or it could be something completely different. It is part of a research and I'm not going to elaborate about what gave those answers. I would however
 like to simply compare those groups.

Comment: The main goal now is to test whether the groups' parallel session (day1 session 3 in all. or day2 session 1 in all. etc') are significantly different. Should I just use a t test?
Next, I would like to test the rate of improvement of the different groups - perhaps compare difference and/or ratio of day1S1 (day1session1) to day1S3 in all groups. 
The Spearman coefficient is not relevant here as it is most likely significant in all groups. However it is an idea, to test the difference in the Spearman coefficient among the different groups. (If that's what you meant, it is a great idea!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time -series data is not a problem here..You have data including repeated measures for various subjects.There are four groups of students .Hence, to ascertain whether the groups differ in terms of learning (language), you may apply ANOVA  I.e. F-test. In case, calculated F- statistic is greater than the table value  at a specific level of significance (say, 5%), the conclusion will be that one or more of four groups do have statistically significant differences. FURTHER, If you have grouped the students in terms of learning styles, you can make a statement that learning styles  differ across various groups.

Comment: What if I would like to compare the difference over different days. Let's say in the second day the difference was distinct, but in the 3rd one it wasn't as much. Should I just do F-tests for each day?

Comment: Consider accepting the answer if you think that it is O.K. Shall try to respond  your new querry later - on.

Comment: THE difference over days (3 in all) shall need application of F - test.  If the comparison  between two days such as1, 2 or 1,3 is intended , take a recourse to  t'- test .